# special value set error in oracle ebs form

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms, oracle-ebs

When I define the special value set on validation set and define the pl/sql in the special validation routines. Then, try to click the list of val to select the record but the result is fail. Then, the error message "APP-FND-01564 ORACLE error 6550 in fdxpls".

oracle ebs form R12.2.5

```
FND PLSQL "DECLARE 
  v_sec_inv VARCHAR2(15);
   BEGIN 

     SELECT msi.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME
     INTO v_sec_inv
   FROM MTL_SECONDARY_INVENTORIES msi, 
       ( SELECT rcvt.TRANSACTION_ID,
                rcvt.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                rcvt.RECEIPT_NUM, 
                rcvt.attribute1, 
                rcvt.attribute2 
           FROM rcv_transactions rcv, apps.RCV_VRC_TXS_VENDINT_V rcvt
            WHERE rcv.TRANSACTION_ID = rcvt.TRANSACTION_ID
             AND rcv.ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY = 'EXP'
             AND rcv.PROJECT_ID IS NOT NULL
         ) a
      WHERE  msi.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = a.attribute1
         AND NVL(msi.subinventory_type, 1)  = 1
         AND NVL(msi.disable_date, SYSDATE + 1) > TRUNC(SYSDATE)
         AND msi.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = v_sec_inv    
     ;

   EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN

     fnd_message.set_name('ABC_EXP_SUBINV_NEW','FLEX_VALIDATE_ERROR');
      fnd_message.set_token('VAL','Please enter the vaild subinventory');
        fnd_message.raise_error;        
     END;"
```

The result is fail and show the below of error message:

APP-FND-01564: ORACLE error 6550 in fdxpls

Casue: fdxpls fail due to ORA-06550: line 1, column 1183:
  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

;'

Comment: Well, code you posted looks OK, so *maybe* it doesn't cause that error. What looks suspicious is what Oracle says: **line 1, column 1183** - as if there 's some code which is written in a single line, and there's something wrong, not necessarily at column 1183.

Comment: @Littlefoot When you put PL/SQL into a special validation set in Oracle EBS, Oracle strips out all new-line characters.  But it is still only 999 characters.  My guess is the OP has a "--" style comment in his PL/SQL that he omitted from the question-as-posted.  "--" style comments kill you (again, because Oracle strips the new line characters, meaning that you're really commenting out the whole rest of your block).

Comment: Ben, check my comment to Littlefoot above.  Also note that your logic isn't going to ever work.  The condition `AND msi.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = v_sec_inv ` will always cause a no_data_found, because `v_sec_inv` is always null.  I think you want to use the bind variable that Oracle gives you: `:!value` instead.

Comment: Aha. Didn't know that (I don't know EBS either). Thank you, @Matthew.

Comment: Hi, Matthew. Thanks for your comment. May I know the solution as "AND msi.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = :!value". right? If yes, the error message is still to show.